# Windows 10: sticking several domain accounts to the login screen

Tags: domain, users, entra-id

I would like to stick permanently 3 domain users to the login screen in Windows 10. So that they choose their account and enter the PIN, but without entering the login and password. Is it possible?
Domain: Azure Active Directory.
Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, sorry.

You can display *local* user accounts on the logon screen, but not domain ones.